# Fourier transform on the scaling equation

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, wavelets

Given the scaling equation of an multiresolution analysis, namely 
$$\varphi=\sqrt{2}\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}^{}h_k\varphi(2\cdot -k)$$
in $L²(ℝ)$-sense. Does this equation also hold on the fourierside, d.h. after used the Fouriertransform in $L²$ in L²-sense? 
Because using Fouriertransform one gets

\begin{align*}
\hat{\varphi}&=\sqrt{2}\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=-n}^{n}h_k \hat{\varphi(2\cdot -k)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}^{}h_k e^{-\frac{-ik\cdot }{2}}\hat{\varphi}\left(\frac{\cdot }{2}\right)\\
&=H\left(\frac{\cdot }{2}\right)\hat{\varphi}\left(\frac{\cdot }{2}\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Do you mean $\hat \phi=\sum_k \langle \hat \phi,\hat\phi_k\rangle \hat\phi_k$? Btw, please use "\langle" and "\rangle" instead of "<" and ">" for inner products, and "i.e." instead of "d.h.". ;)

Comment: I changed notation to make it more obvious @MaoWao

Comment: I think i got the answer. $\hat{\varphi}=H\left(\frac{\cdot }{2}\right)\hat{\varphi}\left(\frac{\cdot }{2}\right)$ holds in L²-sense because of the Plancherel-formula in L², right? But it ALSO holds almost everywhere because of Charlesons theorem, or?